# how to remove the default option and make the single page checkout?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

hi I want to make my checkout page as a single page chekout with the billing, payment, shipping method and order review options. I search a lot on the net but i only find some extensions which are not working.
Can anyone please tell me how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please used below extension for onestep chekcout

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout.html